# How to remove Javascript reference programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page in which I have used scriptmanager and added external js to it.
In my child page I want some other js files which are conflicting with the js (e.g. Jquery plugins) files that are in master page. Is there any way to remove script reference from the master page for that specific child page. I have also tried scriptmanagerproxy but still conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a jQuery script to manipulate and remove the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("link[type='text/css']").remove(); 
         // or
       $("link[href='Styles/Site.css']").remove();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to add a property in master page

```
    private bool addScriptMasterPage = true;
    public bool AddScriptMasterPage
    {
        get
        {
            return addScriptMasterPage;
        }
        set
        {
            addScriptMasterPage = value;
        }
    }
```

then in page that you don't want load script from master page, use

```
    MasterPage master = (MasterPage)this.Master;
    MasterPage.AddScriptMasterPage = false;
```

and i load of master page register the scripts only when the property is true.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("key", "url.js")
```

This is not a javascript way, but can work in another way